# How to add sources to .jar and .so libraries used by Android app for debugging purposes

Tags: android, cmake, jar, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have an Android app which uses 3rd party .jar and .so libraries. I have the sources for the 3rd party project which builds the libraries. How can I modify my Android Studio project to add the 3rd party sources so that I could debug the native code? Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code

Comment: Thanks Michael, I already saw this useful article. The question is about adding sources to the existing pre-built libraries (I don't have a way to build them) for debugging and this article doesn't help unless I missed something.

Comment: Have the prebuilt libraries been built with debug information? If yes, then if you are using `lldb`, you can do `target symbols add <path-to-so-on-computer>`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-debugger might be what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks Dan, I tried it but it wouldn't let me attach sources (no "attach" tab) for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do something like this in gradle:

```
       sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs += "${SOURCE_DIR}/path"
        }
    }
   preBuild.doFirst {
        copy {
            from file("${SOURCE_DIR}/path/resources/somefile.xxx")
            into file('src/main/assets')
        }
   }
   externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version "3.10.0+"
            path file("${SOURCE_DIR}/path/cpp/CMakeLists.txt")
        }
    }
```